# Pythonanywhere Database Configurations

Tags: python, django, database, pythonanywhere

I have a remote database server in godaddy. I want to use that for database connectivity for my Django Project. Because, I want to access the data stored in pythonanywhere database and it is said that, it is accessible unless you have the SSH keys which is provided only if you have paid account.

Is there a way to configure the settings.py database values to access it remotely from a java program?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not fan of godaddy  for hosting, change from godaddy to heroku. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

Comment: How can I access the data if it's heroku? I know how to host there, but access the data is the important criterion for me right now

Comment: `heroku pg:psql`. You need to first deploy your application on heroku and they have #1 documentation to explore. Sometime you have to do google too. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you trying to access GoDaddy database from within PythonAnywhere? (if so, you will have to deal with GoDaddy security restrictions/rules on their database) Or are you trying to access a PythonAnywhere database from GoDaddy/somewhere else? (In which case, you would have to deal with PythonAnywhere security rules- which means that you will have to use ssh tunnelling for this use case)

In any case, if the database you need to access is only available over ssh tunnelling, check out the [sshtunnel python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sshtunnel).